# set validate to default to true with Backbone "set"

Tags: validation, backbone.js

In the code I am working with using Backbone 1.0.0, the validate function of my model is only called when I go:

```
myThing.set( "title", "My title string", { validate : true } );
```

Is there a way in the initialize function of my model to set the default to true so that this:

```
myThing.set( "title", "My title string" );
```

Would cause the validate function to be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no way to override the default behaviors of the methods, but you can still override the `set` method directly, something like:

```
var set = Backbone.Model.prototype.set;
Backbone.Model.prototype.set = function(key, val, options) {
  return set.call(this, key, val, _.extend({validate: true}, options));
}
```

Keep in mind that the `set` method has to deal with 2 different cases (as it allows to pass an object as argument as well). So this example won't work all the time. You can refer to the actual Backbone code to see an example of how it's done.

Comment: @muistooshort true, I carelessly thought that the context would be kept while obviously not as `set` is just a random function.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @Loamhoof is very incomplete. Here's a complete solution:

```
/**
 * @file
 * A Backbone Model subclass that enforces validation when calling set().
 */

(function (Backbone) {

"use strict";

Backbone.MyBaseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  initialize: function (options) {
    this.__initialized = true;
    return Backbone.Model.prototype.initialize.call(this, options);
  },

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  set: function (key, val, options) {
    if (this.__initialized) {
      // Deal with both the "key", value and {key:value}-style arguments.
      if (typeof key === 'object') {
        key.validate = true;
      }
      else {
        if (!options) {
          options = {};
        }
        options.validate = true;
      }
    }
    return Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, key, val, options);
  }

});

}(Backbone));
```

Comment: For clarity: the initialization handling is there too ensure that the initial `set()` call doesn't get validated. If you want to validate that too, then you can get rid of the `initialize()` method and the `this.__initialized` check.

Comment: Well, it was voluntary incomplete. As for your answer, `key.validate = true;` should be `val.validate = true`. Also, `options.validate = true;` will prevent the user from overriding your now default behavior (he can't skip the validation). I must be missing something, but what's the purpose of your `__initialized` attribute?  As a side-note, overriding the `initialize` method this way will remove additional arguments (you never know), why not use `Backbone.Model.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);` instead?

Comment: Ironically, I first had `val.validate = true` too, but that's clearly wrong. I wonder why you're making the same mistake I did :) It's true that the user can't skip validation anymore; that's intentional in my app. The purpose of the `__initialized` variable is to skip validation when constructing/initializing a model. Additional arguments for `initialize()` are not part of the Backbone API and therefor not supported.

Comment: And I know that it was voluntarily incomplete, but I thought it'd be helpful for others if they could start from a more complete answer :)

Comment: I'm ok with all of these as it's simply your philosophy. But I still disagree for the `key.validate`. If you pass an objet as first argument, the options are contained within the second one, ie `val`. Setting `validate` to `true` in the `key` object will just add an unwanted attribute to the model and won't ensure the validation. I must be missing something there.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you!

```
 set: function (key, val, options) {
    if (!options) {
      options = {};
      options.validate = true;
    }
    return Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, key, val, options);
  }
```